# .htaccess https 301 redirect + mobile site redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile, https

I'm trying to set up a permanet 301 redirect from all non-https and www version of my site to the https version while at the same time having all the mobile traffic redirected to the mobile version located on a subdomain

After reading a few tutorials I was able to assemble this (which works) :

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off               [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https:// site here [R=301,L,NE]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)

RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:https:// site here]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 


RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]


RewriteRule ^ https://m. site here [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
```

The script does works but the problem I have is it creates 2 landing page redirects(http,www ---> https AND https:// ---> https://m.) which slows down the process and has a bad effect on seo.

Could someone point me to a good solution to redirect all mobile traffic to https://m. AND everything else to https://...

I have also tried to use php headers to fix the issue but it creates the same problem

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .htacces does the redirect from http to https first. And then does the redirect for mobile traffic. Which result in two redirects for non-https mobile traffic.

If you do the mobile redirect first it should leave with only one redirect for all situations.